# Is there an R function similar to foreach loops in Stata for creating new variables based on the name (or root) of existing variables?

Tags: r, stata, dplyr

I have a list of 60 variables (30 pairs, essentially), and I need to combine the information across all the pairs to create new variables based on the data stored in each pair.

To give some context, I am working on a systematic review of prediction model studies, and I extracted data on which variables were **considered** for inclusion in the prediction model of each study (the first 30 variables) and which variables were **included** in the model (the second 30 variables)

All variables are binary.

The first 30 variables are written in the form “p_[varname]”
The second 30 are written in the form “p_[varname]_inc”. 
I want to create a new variable that is called [varname] and takes the values “Not considered”, “Considered”, and “Included”.

In Stata, I could easily do this like so:

```
  foreach v of [varname1]-[varname30] {
gen `v' = "Not considered" if p_`v' == 0
replace `v' = "Considered" if p_`v' == 1 & p_`v'_inc == 0
replace `v' = "Included" if p_`v'_inc == 1 & p_`v'_inc == 1
}
```

In R, the only way I can figure out to do it is by copy and pasting the same ifelse statement for all variables, for example:

```
predictor_vars %>% 
  mutate(age = ifelse(p_age==1 & p_age_inc==1, "Included", 
                      ifelse(p_age==1 & p_age_inc==0, "Considered", "Not considered")),
         sex = ifelse(p_sex==1 & p_sex_inc==1, "Included", 
                      ifelse(p_sex==1 & p_sex_inc==0, "Considered", "Not considered")), 
....
         [varname] = ifelse([varname]==1 & [varname]_inc==1, "Included", 
                      ifelse([varname]==1 & [varname]==0, "Considered", "Not considered"))
)
```

Is there an easier way to do this in R / dplyr?

Edit: Sorry for not providing enough detail before (new here, but really appreciate the fast responses!). Here is a sample of the data

```
structure(list(p_age = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), label = "Age", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric")), p_age_inc = structure(c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
), label = "Age", class = c("labelled", "numeric")), p_sex = structure(c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), label = "Sex", class = c("labelled", "numeric"
)), p_sex_inc = structure(c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Sex", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric")), p_nation = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Nationality / country", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric")), p_nation_inc = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), label = "Nationality / country", class = c("labelled", "numeric"
)), p_prevtb = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Treatment regimen / treatment status (retreatment)", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric")), p_prevtb_inc = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), label = "Previous TB / retreated TB", class = c("labelled", 
"numeric"))), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

The first 5 rows (with 4 sets of selected predictors) looks like this:

```
  p_age p_age_inc p_sex p_sex_inc p_nation p_nation_inc p_prevtb
1     1         1     1         1        0            0        0
2     1         0     1         0        0            0        0
3     1         0     1         1        0            0        0
4     1         1     1         1        0            0        0
5     1         1     1         0        1            0        1
6     1         1     1         0        1            0        1
  p_prevtb_inc
1            0
2            0
3            0
4            0
5            0
6            0
```

And I'd like to create the new variables like this:

```
  p_age p_age_inc p_sex p_sex_inc p_nation p_nation_inc p_prevtb
1     1         1     1         1        0            0        0
2     1         0     1         0        0            0        0
3     1         0     1         1        0            0        0
4     1         1     1         1        0            0        0
5     1         1     1         0        1            0        1
6     1         1     1         0        1            0        1
  p_prevtb_inc        age        sex         nation         prevtb
1            0   Included   Included Not considered Not considered
2            0 Considered Considered Not considered Not considered
3            0 Considered   Included Not considered Not considered
4            0   Included   Included Not considered Not considered
5            0   Included Considered     Considered     Considered
6            0   Included Considered     Considered     Considered
```

Comment: There will be a way to do it.  But it would be easier to work out exactly how to do it with some test data.  Could you give us the output from `dput(predictor_vars)` or `dput(head(predictor_vars))` please?  Also, what possible values (and desired result) are there for variables `p_XXX` not equal to `1`?

Comment: Hi, can you provide a sample of your `predictor_vars` data frame, e.g. copy/paste the output of `dput(head(predictor_vars, 50))`

Comment: Thanks @Limey and Valeri!  I edited the post above to include more details. Please let me know if you need additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution could be improved upon but it works. The function does what the question asks for creating the variables in a standard `for` loop over the `p_*` variables. And then returns the result.

Argument `Bind` can be used to return just the newly created variables by setting `Bind = FALSE`.

```
create_var <- function(X, Bind = TRUE){
  xnames <- names(X)
  p_only <- grep('p_([^_]+$)', xnames, value = TRUE)
  res <- vector('list', length = length(p_only))
  for(i in seq_along(p_only)){
    x <- X[[ p_only[i] ]]
    y <- X[[paste0(p_only[i], '_inc')]]
    res[[i]] <- case_when(
      as.logical(x) & as.logical(y) ~ "Included",
      as.logical(x) & !as.logical(y) ~ "Considered",
      !as.logical(x) ~ "Not considered",
      TRUE ~ "Not considered"
    )
  }
  names(res) <- sub('^p_', '', p_only)
  res <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, res)
  if(Bind) cbind(X, res) else res
}

create_var(df1)
df1 %>% create_var()
df1 %>% create_var(Bind = FALSE)
```